# NullPointerException in JXL when creating a workbook

Tags: java, jxl

The program works fine on another PC. I imported it on my home PC, where it doesn't work.

Line of error:

```
wwbCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("bstncopy.xls"), wbook);
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jxl.read.biff.ExternalSheetRecord.getNumRecords(ExternalSheetRecord.java:135)
    at jxl.write.biff.ExternalSheetRecord.<init>(ExternalSheetRecord.java:107)
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.<init>(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:219)
    at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:325)
    at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:306)
    at ReadDataBst.<init>(ReadDataBst.java:28)
    at Graph.<init>(Graph.java:23)
    at Dijkstra.<init>(Dijkstra.java:4)
    at GUIWindowBuilder.<init>(GUIWindowBuilder.java:28)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

Comment: Perhaps `wbook` is `null`? Or `bstncopy.xls` doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, it looks like your code attempts to dereference a null pointer, hence the NullPointerException. As you suggested the line of error:

```
wwbCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("bstncopy.xls"), wbook);
```

did you check that `Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("bstncopy.xls"))` returns a non-null object or `wbook` is a non-null object before this point?

I believe the problem is associated with those two entities being null. So, before creating work book, check if both the items associated with the line of error are not null object.

You can do something like this.

```
File file = new File("bstncopy.xls");
if(file != null && wbook != null){
    wwbCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbook); 
}
```

Comment: I don't know how check this, since wbook and wwbcopy doesn't show up in the variables in the debug mode, which I don't understand.. btw I'm beginner.

Comment: According to your code the workbook is not null. Why is the workbook not shown as a variable in debug mode?

Comment: which workbook you are talking about? `wbook` object? be careful, `wbook` looks like a variable in your given line but `Workbook` is a class. so, `Workbook` won't show up in the debug mode. by the way, if you have a different question, ask multiple question in stackoverflow. you can google as well to get some debugging help.

Comment: I am talking about wbook
wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(stream);

But anyway, what can I do now to solve this error. We figured out that wbook is not null, what else could be null then?

Comment: @SymbioseStudios did you check `file` is null or not? with code snippet provided, are you still getting null pointer exception?

Comment: Oh, status and path of file is null, but it still passes the if statement file != null && wbook != null. I don't get it..

Comment: you have to find it yourself because without seeing your code, i am unable to comment anything.

Comment: Ok, still no idea how but thank you for your support so far.

Comment: @SymbioseStudios if my answer helped you, you can accept it. you can also post another question with your complete code. then probably you can find some help to identify your problem.